# What will be best "formula" for this mixed effects model

Tags: r, statistics, regression, lme4, mixed-models

I have following study which I want to analyze with Mixed effects model:

"Subjects" are divided in two "Group" (Treatment A and B).

"Weight" is recorded before and 3 months ("Time") after treatment (repeated measures).

Need to correct for subjects "age" and "gender" also.

**Main question is:** Whether two groups differ in their effect on weight?

For Mixed effects, I was considering following syntax with `lmer` function of `lme4` package:

```
lmer(weight ~ Group*Time + age, (1|subject) + (1|gender), data=mydata)
```

Is this syntax correct or do I need to use more complex terms such as ones given below:

```
(time|subject)
(time + 1|subject)
(1|subject) + (1|Group:subject) + (1|Time:subject)
```

I have tried to see different sources on the internet but literature seems to be very confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gender` should not be a random effect (intercept). It doesn't meet any of the usual requirements for it to be treated as random.

```
(time|subject)
```

and

(time + 1|subject)

are the same. It means you are allowing the fixed effect of `time` to vary at different levels of `subject`

```
(1|subject) + (1|Group:subject) + (1|Time:subject)
```

makes very little sense. This says that `Time` is nested in `subject` because `(1|Time:subject)` is the samee as `(1|subject:Time)` and `(1|subject) + (1|subject:Time)` is the definition of how to specify nested random effects. The addition of `(1|Group:subject)` seems bizarre and I would be surprised if such a model is identified. Your research question is *"Whether two groups differ"* so this means you want to know the fixed effect of Group, so `(1|Group:subject)` does not make sense.

The model:

```
lmer(weight ~ Group*Time + age + gender, (1|subject), data=mydata)
```

makes sense.

Finally, this question should be on Cross Validated.

Comment: Thanks for a well explained answer. Cross-validated is not for programming issues so I posted here. This site https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55124966/correct-model-in-r-using-lmer states that we should have "maximal" random effects. How can we have that in my study?

Comment: CV is not for programming but this is not a programming question. Thanks for the link to that question, I may post a comment to that answer. The "Keep it Maximal" advice by Barr et al (2013) is more often than not very bad advice and one of the main reasons for so many questions on CV from people with problems with models that don't converge of have singular fit. Instead read the paper by Bates (the primary author of the lme4 package) [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.04967)

Comment: If you really want to "keep it maximal" then you want: `lmer(weight ~ Group*Time + age + gender, (Time|subject), data=mydata)` You can't fit random slopes for `Group`, `age` or `gender` because they don't vary by `subject` and you don't want any other grouping variables (on the right side of `|`) for the reasons I wrote in this answer.

Comment: What does `(group*time|subject)` mean? Does it make sense as maximal random effect? Also, please provide a link to read about syntax of mixed models (which term to keep on each side or vertical bar).

Comment: It means that `group`, `time` and the `group:time` interaction are allowed to vary by `subject`. However, `group` does not vary by subject so it does not make sense to specify this and `lmer` should produce an error if you do.

Comment: If, in some other study, same subject get both types of treatments (and weight is measured each time on two occassions- pre and post 3 months), then it may make sense.

Comment: If a variable varies by subject then yes it makes sense *mathematically*, and conceptually there is nothing wrong with it, but whether the data suppors such a model is another matter entirely. Please read the Bates et al (2015) paper.

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. FYI I have posted an answer to the question you linked to earlier [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55124966/correct-model-in-r-using-lmer/62840563#62840563)